# how to enforce some spacing between the elements of 'addCategoryAxis'

Tags: d3.js

My goal is to make a bar chart that demonstrates the number of jobs advertised in particular locations.

I'm using this code, it draws on [d3](https://d3js.org/) and also dimple:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function draw(data) {
  /*
    D3.js setup code
  */
      "use strict";
      var margin = 75,
          width = 1400 - margin,
          height = 600 - margin;

      var svg = d3.select("body")
                  .append("svg")
                  .attr("width", width + margin)
                  .attr("height", height + margin)
                  .append('g')
                  .attr('class','chart');
  /*
    Dimple.js Chart construction code
  */
      var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg, data);
      myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", "Location");
      myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "Jobs");

      myChart.addSeries(null, dimple.plot.bar);
      myChart.draw();
    };
  </script>
```

It more or less works, but the thing is- the result is pretty useless because the X axis is so crowded that each individual location is essentially invisible.

Is there a way to enforce some reasonable amount of spacing there so that the different locations remain legible in such a way that it can withstand more records being added at a later date- so- with some kind of dynamism.

[image]

Comment: Just increase the width of the graph so you have to pan left and right to view more data. By the way how are you capable of asking more than one question within 90 minutes ?

Comment: I thought it was one, well it was when I last time tried. Anyway, if you need a hand create a fiddle of your graph and Ill take a look but what I previously said should do the trick, atleast it will in D3, I haven't used Dimple

Comment: when I put `width = 1400 - margin,` to `width = 14000 - margin,` the whole chart just disappeared. is it possible that I should use css?

Comment: I don't think I would use CSS in this case, there's numerous ways of doing this. Mock up a fiddle and ill take a look

Comment: is there a way to put the data into fiddle? - nevermind-  i think I got it

Comment: that worked- increasing the margin- I just had to adjust it- I guess it can't be too big or something. it's kind of hard to add data to fiddle

Comment: increasing the width worked ? If you solved it add an answer for others to see how :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so- on the advice of @thisOneGuy I started playing around with increasing the width, and it worked.

At first I tried to increase the width too much and the chart just disappeared (*if anyone knows why that happened I would be interested to hear about it in the comments perhaps*)

from `width = 1400 - margin,` to `width = 14000 - margin,` it disappears

but `width = 9000 - margin,` was ok.

you can find the result [here](http://smatthewenglish.com/26.04/)